# Why does Google Maps sometimes return English address when it should return a Chinese address

Tags: api, google-maps, internationalization

This is my search api call:

```
http://ditu.google.cn/maps/geo?q=39.544387,115.799217&output=xml&sensor=true_or_false&key=abcdefg
```

and it returns a Chinese address,

but sometimes I find it returns an English address stored in my `mysql` database,

so what's wrong with it?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Usually Google returns funny things when it cannot locate the address. Did you check the return code?

Answer (score 0):

Have you set the language property?

http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/reference.html#GeocoderRequest